# C runtime error "Segmentation Fault" - how to remove it?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, clang

I am not sure why I am getting a segmentation fault in my code. However, I know that it occurs within the `while(*word == *grid_char)` block. I have also tries to remove the code within it and see what happens and I still get a segmentation fault error. However, If I remove that while loop completely, the error disappears.

I know what seg fault is but I cannot understand why the error appears in this case. I also don't know how to debug it.

Here is my code.

```
  char grid[(MAX_DIM_SIZE + 1) * MAX_DIM_SIZE + 1];
  char dictionary[MAX_DICTIONARY_WORDS * (MAX_WORD_SIZE + 1 ) + 1 ];
  int dictionary_idx[MAX_DICTIONARY_WORDS];

  char *grid_char;
  char *match_word;

  int grid_idx = 0;
  char *word = dictionary + dictionary_idx[0];
  int word_found = 0;
  int max_grid_height = row; // max y (max_grid_height) on grid
  int row = 0;
  int grid_clm = 0;

  // print_char(grid[18]);

  while (grid[grid_clm] != '\n')
  {
    row = 0;

    while(row < max_grid_height)
    {
      word = dictionary + dictionary_idx[0]; //first char from dictionary ***


      while(*word != '\0')
      {

        // print_char(*word);

        int match_row = row; // back to start point grid - using this to compare potential match
        match_word = word; // back to start point dict - using this to compare potential match

        grid_char = grid[grid_clm + max_grid_length*match_row];

        print_char(grid_char);
        print_char(*word);
        print_char(*(match_word+1));
        print_char(' ');

        while(*word == *grid_char)
        {
          match_row++;
          match_word++;

          if ((*match_word == '\n' || *match_word == '\0'))
          {
            print_char('F');
            continue;
          }
          if(match_row >= max_grid_height){
            break;
          }

          grid_char = grid[grid_clm + max_grid_length*match_row];
        }

        // next dictionary word
        while(*word != '\n' && *word != '\0'){
          word++;

        }
        if (*word == '\0'){
          break;
        }
        word++;
        // print_char(' ');

      }
      row++; //next grid row
    }
    grid_clm++; //next grid column
  }
```

Comment: Provide minimum compilable code.

Comment: My code also involves reading from two files. How could I include that as well?

Comment: This partial code is hard to analyze. For exanple, `word` is probably a `char *` and if that's true the non-standard `print_char` takes a `char` or an `int` and `print_char(grid_char)` should at least raise a warning. You _did_ compile with warnings on, did you?

Comment: I believe that `match_word = word;` should be `match_word = &word;`, but I could be wrong because it's a little hard to follow.

Comment: How could I make the code easier to read? It reads from two files but I am not sure how I could include them.

Comment: What are `dictionary` and `dictionary_idx`?

Comment: @MOehm I tried that and still doesn't work, I get a warning to add a '&' before `grid[grid_clm + max_grid_length*match_row]` but I am not sure why it asks me to do so.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie sorry , I included these variables now

Comment: `How could I make the code easier to read?` Start by rewriting all `where()` loops into `for()` loops.

Comment: `grid_char` is a `char *`, but `grid[...]` is a character, i.e. a very small integer. By saying `grid_char = grid[...]`, you make a pointer from that small integer, which is later interpreted as address. So the segmentation fault could happen here: `while(*word == *grid_char)`. Do as clang tells you and assign apointer to a pointer: `grid_char = &grid[...]`.

Comment: `char *word = dictionary + dictionary_idx[0];` Is UB, given that `dictionary_idx` is uninitialized. `grid_char = grid[grid_clm + max_grid_length*match_row];` Isn't `grid_char` a `char *`?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, grid_char is char *

Comment: Thanks @MOehm, this solved my problem. I am assuming by adding the & as clang proposes, it stores the reference of `grid[grid_clm + max_grid_length*match_row];` in grid_char.

Comment: `&grid[i]` is a pointer to the char at index `i` in `grid`. Without the `&`, `grid[i]` is the character at that position itself. Familiarize yourself with pointers. You will see them quite often in C. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the initialization of the char pointer grid_char, you are assigning a char value instead of a memory address.